# copy till last row from specific row number with cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code where I need to make it work as below.

1. copy from row 10 till last row with value.
2. the last row will be with reference to column N starting from cell N10..

any suggestions from SO team?

```
    wbSource.Sheets(SITE_TEMPLATE).Rows(10).EntireRow.Copy wbMaster.Sheets(SITE_TEMPLATE).Range("A" & insertRow2)
    insertRow2 = insertRow2 + 1
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for how to find the last row.

Comment: @BigBen hi.. I referred the post. but I need start the search from row 10 with reference to another column. that is where Im stuck!!

Comment: That other post should help you do *exactly* that.

Comment: You know how to find the last row, you did it for `insertRow2`. All you need to do is find and assign the last row for `Column N` to a variable, and modify `.Rows(10)` to `.Rows(10 & ":" & wbSourceLastRow)`, or what ever you want to name the variable

Comment: @BigBen I came upto this. but its not copying till end row. ```lrow = wrSource.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wrSource.Range("N10"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

            'copying row 10 from sheet 2 with name "Site Creation Template(Project)"
            wbSource.Sheets(SITE_TEMPLATE).Rows(10 & ":" & lrow).EntireRow.Copy wbMaster.Sheets(SITE_TEMPLATE).Range("A" & insertRow2)```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Workbooks("wbSource").Worksheets("SITE_TEMPLATE")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

        .Rows(10 & ":" & LastRow).EntireRow.Copy wbMaster.Sheets(SITE_TEMPLATE).Range("A" & insertRow2)

        insertRow2 = insertRow2 + 1

    End With

End Sub
```